# Additional scripts in PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, path, homebrew

I am trying to install Rails on OS X 10.7.5, using Homebrew and continue to receive the below Warning.  I have tried many times to change the PATH to exclude the Python Directories (modifying .bash_profile, but am not even sure this is what is causing the Warning. Apologies if this is serious noob territory, but I could not find anything helpful after hours of searching. Homebrew warning:

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
```

`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python-config
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python2.5-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/curl-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncurses5-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncursesw5-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xml2-config
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xslt-config
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make installation of Rails using gem tool . Rails is just a gem and in should not be installed by homebrew . First install the newest version of Ruby , then google a little about gem management system and give it a go . Here is a nice [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/310-getting-started-with-rails?view=asciicast) on the subject.

Comment: Thanks- I did use Railsinstaller initially, and it suggested using Homebrew to help with the additional software installations.  I keep receiving this Warning and it appears to be the cause of my errors when trying to install rails.

Comment: Anyway , you'll encounter problems , but don't give up .Ruby and Rails are so exiting . You can try to install Ruby using RVM or rbenv , then the road is open .

Comment: Not giving up- trying everything under the sun. RVM installs Rails, then says immediately says rails is not installed when I ask for the version.  I believe this is due to the above config script errors...

Comment: I guess you mean RVM installs Ruby , you check ruby -v , is it OK ? If it is , then you type $> gem install rails

Comment: Yes, ruby -v checks out to v1.9.3, then i enter

Comment: Yes, ruby -v checks out to v1.9.3, then i enter sudo rails install, which completes.  Then when I check for rails version, it says no rails is installed.  I think my PATH is incorrect which makes it not recognize the installed version?

Comment: The command is : gem install rails . Gem is a tool for managing parts of the rails framework . You can check for gem by typing : gem -v