# failing to doctoring homebrew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, homebrew, bash

I get this message when running `brew doctor`

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

    /opt/local/bin/freetype-config
    /opt/local/bin/gpg-error-config
    /opt/local/bin/icu-config
...
```

following some informations I gathered on `SO`, I updated my `.bash_profile` with this

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.16/site/bin:/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.16/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/ant/bin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin:/Users/benchoufi/bin:/Users/mehdibenchoufi/Desktop/Sites/apache-ant/bin:/usr/local/bro/bin:/opt/bro/bin
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

But I still get the same output when running `brew doctor` (I am using `OSX`)

Comment: Well, that's a warning, why is the title *failing* to doctoring homebrew

Comment: @IanCarroll because I can't silence these warnings, and I think they are a cause of bunch of problems I have

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054605/config-scripts-exist-outside-your-system-or-homebrew-directory?rq=1

Comment: @IanCarroll sorry but I installed `rails` using `gem install` not with homebrew..